# SQL less than 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql

i need to make a selection of all the values of the same order_ID, where the difference between the first date and the last is equal or less than 7, but I can't figure out how I should do this, could any one give me some help how I should do this?

DB layout:

```
+---------------+---------------------+
| order_ID      | date                |
+---------------+---------------------+
|             1 | 2012-01-21 09:15:00 |
|             1 | 2012-01-21 09:15:00 |
|             2 | 2012-01-21 14:15:00 |
|             3 | 2012-01-22 10:05:00 |
|             3 | 2012-01-22 10:05:00 |
|             4 | 2012-01-22 14:25:00 |
|             5 | 2012-01-25 11:05:00 |
|             6 | 2012-01-27 16:10:00 |
|             6 | 2012-01-27 16:10:00 |
|             7 | 2012-01-27 16:10:00 |
|             8 | 2012-01-28 15:55:00 |
|             9 | 2012-01-28 16:40:00 |
|            10 | 2012-01-28 17:35:00 |
|            10 | 2012-01-28 17:35:00 |
|            10 | 2012-02-03 09:35:00 |
|            12 | 2012-02-03 10:15:00 |
|            13 | 2012-02-05 13:25:00 |
|            14 | 2012-02-05 13:45:00 |
|            15 | 2012-02-05 14:10:00 |
|            15 | 2012-02-05 14:10:00 |
|            16 | 2012-02-07 15:45:00 |
|            17 | 2012-02-11 11:50:00 |
|            18 | 2012-02-11 12:45:00 |
|            19 | 2012-02-14 09:10:00 |
|            19 | 2012-02-16 13:05:00 |
|            19 | 2012-02-16 13:05:00 |
|            20 | 2012-02-17 09:40:00 |
|            21 | 2012-02-19 14:10:00 |
|            21 | NULL                |
|            22 | 2012-02-25 10:20:00 |
|            23 | 2012-02-25 11:05:00 |
|            24 | 2012-02-25 13:35:00 |
|            25 | 2012-02-27 17:10:00 |
|            26 | 2012-03-03 09:40:00 |
|            27 | 2012-03-05 10:45:00 |
|            28 | NULL                |
|            29 | NULL                |
|            29 | NULL                |
|            29 | NULL                |
|            30 | NULL                |
|            30 | NULL                |
+---------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to decide how you want to handle nulls (coalesce to the maximum or minimum date value?), but this should give you a basic structure for your query.

```
select order_id
from (
    select order_id, min(date) as mindate, max(date) as maxdate
    from tbl
    group by order_id) t
where datediff(maxdate,mindate) <= 7
```

Comment: Wow nice, thanks,
but why is there a "t" behind the from(...) ?

Comment: @Kiwi It's an alias. You can refer to the result of the subquery by using `t`. It's useful when selecting from multiple table/subqueries to avoid ambiguity in the column names.